# CustomEditor не работает с ScriptableObject

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

CustomEditor:

```
    [CustomEditor(typeof(DefaultItemsData))]
    public class ItemsToCreateItemEditor : UnityEditor.Editor
    {
        private void OnEnable()
        {
            Debug.Log("Enable");
        }
        
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            Debug.Log("OnInspectorGUI");
            
            var myScript = (object)target as Item;
 
            var flag = GUILayout.Toggle(myScript.CanBeCreated, "Flag");

            if (myScript.CanBeCreated)
            {
                Debug.Log("True");
                DefaultItemsData instance = CreateInstance<DefaultItemsData>();
                SerializedObject serializedInstance = new UnityEditor.SerializedObject(instance);
                SerializedProperty serializedPropertyMyInt = serializedInstance.FindProperty("Item");
            }
        }
    }
```

DefaultItemsData:

```
    [CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "DefaultItem", menuName = "Item/DefaultItem")]
    public class DefaultItemsData : ScriptableObject
    {
        [field: SerializeField] public Item Item { get; private set; }
    }
```

Item

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Item
    {
        [field: SerializeField] public bool CanBeCreated { get; private set; }
        [field: SerializeField] public List<ItemToCreateItemList> ItemsToCreateItem { get; private set; }
    }
```

Что я хочу сделать? Я хочу отобразить некоторое свойство, если другое свойство является true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из документации [SerializeField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html):

- Первое предложение:

> When Unity serializes your scripts, it only serializes public fields

Что в переводе обозначает: `public` полям атрибут не нужен, они только для `private` или `protected`.

- Критерии работы:

> - CAN serialize public non-static fields (of serializable types)
> - CAN serialize **nonpublic** non-static fields marked with the **[SerializeField] attribute**.
> - CANNOT serialize static fields.
> - **CANNOT serialize properties.**

---

Да, согласен, название `SerializedProperty` может быть обманчиво, хотя в контексте механизма сериализации `Unity`, было бы странно такое думать.

Из документации [SerializedObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.html):

- Первое предложение:

> SerializedObject and **SerializedProperty** are classes for editing **serialized fields** on Unity objects in a completely generic way.

---

А вообще по инспектору можно было заметить, что с свойствами дел не имеют.

Comment: похоже, что либо вы меня не поняли, либо я вас не понял. Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы поле ItemsToCreateItem отображалось только в том случае, если CanBeCreated == true. Но это не так важно. Важно то, что у меня CustomEditor в принципе не работает, то бишь когда я что-то делаю в инспекторе с ScriptableObject в консоль ничего не выводится(по CustomEditor раскиданы Debug.Log).

Comment: Я все прекрасно понял. Но похоже, что вы либо анлийского не понимаете, либо `C#`, либо и того и того. Тут вас с этим не помочь.

Answer (score -1):

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(DefaultItemsData))]
public class ItemsToCreateItemEditor : UnityEditor.Editor
{
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Debug.Log("Enable");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnInspectorGUI");

        var myScript = (object)target as DefaultItemsData;

        myScript.Item.CanBeCreated = GUILayout.Toggle(myScript.Item.CanBeCreated, "Flag");

        if (myScript.Item.CanBeCreated)
        {
            Debug.Log("True");
            DefaultItemsData instance = CreateInstance<DefaultItemsData>();
            SerializedObject serializedInstance = new UnityEditor.SerializedObject(instance);
            SerializedProperty serializedPropertyMyInt = serializedInstance.FindProperty("Item");
        }
    }
}

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "DefaultItem", menuName = "Item/DefaultItem")]
public class DefaultItemsData : ScriptableObject
{
    public Item Item { get; private set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public bool CanBeCreated { get; set; }
    public List<ItemToCreateItemList> ItemsToCreateItem { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Всё равно не работает